# Oneboxed comments do not show the current version

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments, chat

I posted [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406711/jquery-popup-message-showing-before-button-is-clicked/13406817#comment18317563_13406817) and have since edited it.

I [posted the comment link (after the edit) to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6239277#6239277)

It shows the old version of the comment!

In a comment:
[image: Comment]

In chat:
[image: Chat]

Comment: How long after editing the comment did you link to it?

Comment: @animuson 31 seconds later as you can see by the chat image (i believe)

Comment: Isn't that time how long ago you first posted the comment, not how long ago you edited it?

Comment: @animuson i am not sure. but it was about half a minute later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chat relies on the API for the data for oneboxing, and the API can sometimes take a small amount of time (under a minute) to reflect changes. Since you posted a link to that comment 31 seconds after creating it, it was certainly less than a minute since you had edited it.

If you try posting a link to the [same comment now](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1182896#1182896), you'll see it's correct:

> Dude! Ummm what is this 'Dude' you speak of? — Neal 7 mins ago